# Can you untrain a tensorflow_hub.KerasLayer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub

I have implemented my own version of `MobileNet` in `TensorFlow` and would like to verify it by comparing it against the official `tensorflow_hub` version.

I can get something working easily as so:

```
URL = "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v1_100_224/feature_vector/4"
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer(URL, True, input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)),
    Layers.Dropout(0.2),
    Layers.Dense(len(class_names))
])
```

But this model is already trained. 
I've tried calling `initializer`s, but `tensorflow_hub.KerasLayer`s don't have them.
I've also tried resetting all of the weights with `glorot_uniform()` and `RandomUniform()`, but then the model does not learn at all (and neither does mine, when I do the same randomization of weights).

Can you reinitialize a pre-trained model?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of searching only provided methods for resetting layers that you already have, or restoring them back to what they were when you started with the model.

This is probably far from complete, but maybe someone can build off it!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

def untrain_layer(layer):
    initial_weights = layer.weights

    new_weights = []

    for w in initial_weights:
        print(w.name)
        if "beta" in w.name:
            new_weights.append(K.eval(tf.keras.initializers.zeros())(w.shape))
        elif "gamma" in w.name:
            new_weights.append(K.eval(tf.keras.initializers.ones())(w.shape))
        elif "moving_mean" in w.name:
            new_weights.append(K.eval(tf.keras.initializers.zeros())(w.shape))
        elif "moving_variance" in w.name:
            new_weights.append(K.eval(tf.keras.initializers.ones())(w.shape))
        else:
            new_weights.append(K.eval(tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform())(w.shape))
    layer.set_weights(new_weights)
```

Use:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
feature_extractor = hub.KerasLayer(URL, True, input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3))
untrain_keraslayer(feature_extractor)
```